# Airflow vault configuration

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, vault

I'm installing airflow Helm charts i want to use vault as secret backend so airflow get database connection uri from  vault secrets. Anyone succeed to configure it this way please help. As I couldn't find how to parse vault namespace to airflow and didn't understand the documentation.
T

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished through a customized `airflow.cfg` configuration file. According to the documentation, for HashiCorp Vault secrets backend you need to add the following to your config:

```
[secrets]
backend = airflow.providers.hashicorp.secrets.vault.VaultBackend
backend_kwargs = {
    "connections_path": "connections",
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8200",
    "mount_point": "airflow"
    }
```

You can read how to set these parameters [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-hashicorp/stable/_api/airflow/providers/hashicorp/secrets/vault/index.html#airflow.providers.hashicorp.secrets.vault.VaultBackend) in the docs.

Since you are installing using `helm` charts, you need to be able to inject a custom configuration file to the `airflow` installation. This is provided by the airflow helm chart in `values.yaml` file for the chart, which you can see [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/chart/values.yaml#L408).

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: I configured the chart to get database credentials from hvault, but it seems airflow doesn't contact hvault to get connection uri from hvault and make a default one